# Shell dialog quits when using numberpad

Tags: bash, dialog, putty

When I create a dialog with an input field and then enter some numbers using the number pad on the right side of the keyboard, it quits. It does not quit when I use the numbers on the top of the keyboard...

any ideas how to prevent this? Here an example dialog

```
dialog --backtitle "Dialog Title" --title "Username required" --inputbox "Please enter a username" 8 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It is a putty issue. You need to check the box "Disable application keypad mode" found in the Settings -> Terminal -> Features

[image]